# Update multiple row with insert new data in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, here my existing fields are getting updated but unable to insert a new row, when users checks for a new category it should be added as a new row in the database.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'shop_id' => 'required',
        'sub_category_id' => 'sometimes|required|',
        'is_visible' => 'required',
        'is_active' => 'required',
    ]);
    try {
         $product = Product::find($id);
         $product->name = $request->name;
         $product->shop_id = $request->shop_id;
         $product->is_visible = $request->is_visible;
         $product->is_active = $request->is_active;
         $product->save();



         foreach($request->category_id as $key =>$v){

            $data = array(

                'product_id'=>$id,
                'category_id'=> $v,
                'sub_category_id'=>isset($request->sub_category_id [$key])?$request->sub_category_id [$key]:null,
                'total_quantity'=>$request->total_quantity [$key],
                'quantity_unit'=>$request->quantity_unit [$key]
            );


            $ewast = EwasteItem::where('product_id','=',$id)->where('category_id','=',$request->category_id [$key])->get();

            if ($ewast) {
                $ewasteitem = EwasteItem::where('product_id',$id)->where('category_id',$v);
                $ewasteitem->update($data);
            } else {
                 EwasteItem::insert($data);
            }
        }
        return \Redirect::route('ewaste.index')->with('successMessage', 'Product Updated Successfully.');
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
}
```

[image: check boxes are categories]

Comment: You can use eloquent's `updateOrCreate` to handle this and avoid any conditional logic.

Comment: Its giving this error when creating a new category. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into ewaste_items` (category_id, sub_category_id, total_quantity, quantity_unit, updated_at, created_at) values (8, ?, 4, 1, 2020-04-11 06:44:40, 2020-04-11 06:44:40))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the foreach loop as follow

```
foreach($request->category_id as $key =>$v) {

    $data = array(

        'product_id'=>$id,
        'category_id'=> $v,
        'sub_category_id'=>isset($request->sub_category_id [$key])?$request->sub_category_id [$key]:null,
        'total_quantity'=>$request->total_quantity [$key],
        'quantity_unit'=>$request->quantity_unit [$key]
    );

    $ewasteitem = App\EwasteItem::updateOrCreate(
        ['product_id' => $id, 'category_id' => $v],
        $data
    );
}
```

also, check that in your App\EwasteItem model have $fillable array and it has the element 'product_id'

```
protected $fillable = ['product_id', ...other_column_names];
```

Comment: This code is just updating the existing row where there is `product->id = this` and `category_id->this` but what about a new row which doesn't have existing product id in the table?

Comment: Its giving this error when creating a new category.  `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'product_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `ewaste_items` (`category_id`, `sub_category_id`, `total_quantity`, `quantity_unit`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (8, ?, 4, 1, 2020-04-11 06:44:40, 2020-04-11 06:44:40))`

Comment: `<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EwasteItem extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'ewaste_items';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'sub_category_id',
        'total_quantity',
        'quantity_unit',
        
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
`

Comment: As I can see that 'product_id' is not in the fillable array.

Comment: Let us know is the solution working for you or not?